# Laravel - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

Tags: php, laravel

I am upgrading from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4. Problem is that when I run `composer update` and when it comes to `php artisan optimize` part, I get an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()
```

I've read a couple of questions here on StackOverflow and the answer is to replace this share method with singleton. But where can I find this `share()`?

**EDIT**

My composer.json file:

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "sngrl/sphinxsearch": "dev-master",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.2.*",
        "league/csv": "^8.2",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.3",
        "wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "dev-master",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
        "uxweb/sweet-alert": "^1.4",
        "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "illuminate/support": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/scout": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Project Share() method file is the Following Path:

Your Project >> Vendor >> laravel >> framework >> src >> Illuminate >> Container >> Container.php

Comment your share() method code and put below code.

```
public function singleton($abstract, $concrete = null)
{
   $this->bind($abstract, $concrete, true);
}
```

Comment: It is already done. I have a singleton instead of share function. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @harunB10, Plase share your composer.json file. OR Try with comment all your Third Party ServiceProviders & UnComment one by one (i.e. config/app.php)

Comment: I have same issue, commented share() and added singleton, but still I am getting same error, Its not resolving my issue

Comment: Modifying core code in laravel is ALWAYS an awful idea. It means you break your update path. The answer should contain the issue and a solution that extends or overrides but leaves core code alone.

Answer (score -2):

When installing Maatwebsite/Excel via Composer, certain composer.json configurations might prevent the installation of all dependencies and requirements for the Excel package.

To ensure a clean installation without encountering dependency issues, you can use the following command:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel -W
```

The -W flag or --with-all-dependencies ensures that Composer disregards any constraints or restrictions specified in your project's composer.json file, allowing for a comprehensive installation of all dependencies required by the Maatwebsite/Excel package.

This command facilitates a clear and unobstructed installation process for Maatwebsite/Excel, resolving potential conflicts related to dependencies and ensuring a successful installation.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. That Excel package should not resolve core problems of Laravel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please share more details. I don't see how that other package (which isn't even installed by harunB10) relates to the given problem

Comment: its error is cause by league/csv because I got same error when Install the excel package.