# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share() - LARAVEL 9 EXCEL

Tags: laravel

i want to make export excel using composer require maatwebsite/excel

this is composer.json code
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
"php": "^8.0.2",
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
"laravel/ui": "^4.0",
"maatwebsite/excel": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
"fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
"laravel/pint": "^1.0",
"laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
"mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
"nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
"spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"App\": "app/",
"Database\Factories\": "database/factories/",
"Database\Seeders\": "database/seeders/"
}
},
"autoload-dev": {
"psr-4": {
"Tests\": "tests/"
}
},
"scripts": {
"post-autoload-dump": [
"Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
"@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
"@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
],
"post-root-package-install": [
"@php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');""
],
"post-create-project-cmd": [
"@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
]
},
"extra": {
"laravel": {
"dont-discover": []
}
},
"config": {
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"preferred-install": "dist",
"sort-packages": true,
"allow-plugins": {
"pestphp/pest-plugin": true
}
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}

when i write

```
php artisan vendor:publish –provider=”Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider” –tag=config
```

the error appears as follows:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

  at vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/ExcelServiceProvider.php:159
    155▕     */
    156▕    protected function bindClasses()
    157▕    {
    158▕        // Bind the format identifier
  ➜ 159▕        $this->app['excel.identifier'] = $this->app->share(function($app) {
    160▕            return new FormatIdentifier($app['files']);
    161▕        });
    162▕    }
    163▕ 

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I have followed these tips, but still confused about the share() method in the comments all or not? [Laravel - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979096/laravel-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-foundation-applicationshare)

Answer (score 1):

when this error appeared to me
i found out that i installed old version of Laravel/Excel
even when i try to run `composer dump-autoload` it also showed me the same error
**the solution that worked to me is** `composer update` it upgraded the laravel/Excel

[there is also some solution here that may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36223196/9823077)